# ACL = whitelisting

Tags: security

I feel ACL is like whitelisting, ie, give some users/groups some permission. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, you could certainly make that argument. What answer are you looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes

you can create list of user and where this user access to do some thing

also you can create list of group and assign access then create relation between user and groups

also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list